# I want to add another form for the logged in users inside session for codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, session, authentication

I have this code -

```
  if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){

  $this->load->view('admin_page');

  }
```

Now I want to add new form which logged in users or admin can see. But when i adding form controller like below, its not working and not storing data into database table. The table is another separate table and and its not users table. So I have add the two separate database details In the same model file like this -

```
<?php

Class Login_Database extends CI_Model {

function SaveForm($form_data)
{
    $this->db->insert('post', $form_data);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
 }

 // Insert registration data in database
 public function registration_insert($data) {

 // Query to check whether username already exist or not
 $condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "'";
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('users');
 $this->db->where($condition);
 $this->db->limit(1);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {

 // Query to insert data in database
 $this->db->insert('users', $data);
 if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
 return true;
 }
 } else {
 return false;
 }
}

 // Read data using username and password
 public function login($data) {

 $condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' AND " . "password    
 =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where($condition);
 $this->db->limit(1);
 $query = $this->db->get();

 if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
 return true;
 } else {
 return false;
  }
 }

 // Read data from database to show data in admin page
 public function read_user_information($username) {

 $condition = "username =" . "'" . $username . "'";
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('users');
 $this->db->where($condition);
 $this->db->limit(1);
 $query = $this->db->get();

 if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
 return $query->result();
 } else {
 return false;
 }
 }

 }

 ?>
```

Now how can i add the form when users logged in and they can see the form and when they fill up it, the value will save in database. I tried it but didn't work-

```
 if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){

// My form for separate table goes here

 $this->load->view('admin_page');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? Are you getting any error message?

If the problem is that the form is not showing, then ensure the session is properly set.

If it has to do with the form not submitting, then try echoing the value of $data to be sure it's well formatted the way you wanted it. Note that it has to be an array of key=>value pair where key is the table column name and value is the value you want to insert.